# Javascript to open and paint a new window

Tags: javascript

I m sending an AJax POST request  to a servlet and it returns a file. I need to print the contents of  the file in a new window using javascript.
window.open() sends the request as GET by default. But i need to send a POST request.  Can any one please help me?

Comment: Why would you need a post to copy some file content you got from ajax into a new window??? Seems to me you do not need ajax but simply `<form action="post" target="_blank" action="yourservlet"></form>`

Comment: Thanks mplungjan. But I ve my code like this.

Comment: But I ve everything inside a JS .The concept is When I click a view Link in a page it should  open a pdf and put it a new child window.     my window.open() uses GET request by default. But i need to invoke doPost() of the servlet to get the PDF.i m fed up with this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense to have post to link to a PDF, but try this:

```
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank"></form>
<a href="someservlet?file=somepdf" 
onclick="document.forms[0].action=this.href; document.forms[0].submit(); return false">Somepdf</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a new window.

```
var handle = window.open();
```

Write a form tag to the new page

```
handle.document.write('<form action="pdfsource.jsp" method="post" id="MyForm">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="0123">' +
'</form>');
handle.document.close();
```

Then post that form

```
handle.document.getElementById("MyForm").submit();
```

(Might be som syntax errors, have not had time to test)

Comment: handle.document.getElementById or handle.document.forms[0] - and you need to do a handle.document.close() after the write and no newlines. It is not PHP